# Cocos2d and iphone 5 display

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-5

I've currently got an app on the app store and I need to upload a newer version of the app. Before I didn't include the Default-568h@2x launch image as I don't need to support the new iPhone 5 screen size so this would just add the black lines to the left and right of the screen, which is completely fine. But. The new update has been rejected due to not including the Default-568h@2x launch image. After some research that launch image now has to be included in the app. The problem I have with this is the client doesn't want to spend any more money getting the designer to support this screen size as all the backgrounds will need re-doing and apparently its not a quick and easy job to do.

So does anyone have any ideas how I can keep the old format with the black lines on the left and right hand sides (letterbox format) when using a iphone 5 device and stay at the old dimensions (960x640) for the 3.5 inch display?

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple will reject such attempts. It is their [policy](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3212013b) that new apps and updates support Retina and widescreen devices, effective since May (2013).

Tell your client that it's a simple yes/no decision: either pay for the updated screens designs or don't update the app. Unless of course contractual obligations require you to perform the work, then it's on you.

Comment: So I can't even use a mask on a CCLayer by using the glScissor()?

Comment: would it make any difference to the users? Perhaps if you added some ornaments to either side you might get lucky and it will pass approval. I wouldn't bet on it though.